# Redirect all images in a directory to another website using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects

How can I redirect all `.png` and `.jpg` image URLs within the `/tool/img` directory to another website? Filenames can consist of special (unicode) characters.

For example, the following URL:

```
http://example.com/tool/img/filename-with-special-chars.png
```

Should redirect to:

```
http://newdomain.com/img/filename-with-special-chars.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tool/img/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/tool/img/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/img/$1  [NC,U,QSA]
```

Comment: @Martijn: Not sure why the edit added, what appears to be, a superfluous `RewriteCond` directive?

Comment: I suspect this is non-Apache? On Apache, the `RewriteRule` pattern should start `^tool/img/` in per-directory .htaccess files - the directory prefix (ie. `/` in this case) is removed in the pattern matching. Also, I don't think `U` is a valid flag on Apache?

Comment: I made the image extentions together. This way it's very easy to expand and read (you notice they're all images in a split second). I made the first `RewriteCond` to make a fast, easy readable check for requested uri before we start more complex conditions. The `/` is correct, thats my bad. I didnt add the U flag though. Ill add comments to my edit

Comment: @Martijn: But it is "faster" to check the URI path in the `RewriteRule` directive, rather than `RewriteCond`, and you certainly wouldn't include both. (The `RewriteRule` pattern is checked _before_ the `RewriteCond` directives are processed.)

Comment: its not working in my case